# How do I host a wordpress blog on tor?

Tags: onion-services, web-hosting

How do I go about hosting a wordpress blog as a hidden service? Are there providers who will host it for me? Or will I have to configure it myself?

Comment: See also https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/378218/wordpress-with-tor-onion-service-dual-com-onion-domains-for-same-website

Answer (score 1):

Making a wordpress site accessible over an Onion Service is going to be the same as making any website accessible over tor. Basically just:

1. Make your web server bind only to localhost on a port that's not exposed to the internet (blocked by the firewall)
2. Install and configure Tor with an Onion Service that points to the above locally hosted webserver

If you'd also like to make your wordpress site available on *both* a clearnet domain *and* an Onion Service, that's actually much more difficult.

You can do it with the Mercator plugin, and [some modifications to your webserver config & child theme to handle domain rewriting](https://tech.michaelaltfield.net/2021/02/12/wordpress-multisite-tor-alias/)

Source: https://tech.michaelaltfield.net/2021/02/12/wordpress-multisite-tor-alias/

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of these solutions:

-Real Hosting [http://hosting6iar5zo7c.onion/]: purchase a web space (you have to pay with bitcoin monthly or yearly) and you can also customize some letters of the onion domain. The basic service gives you 256MB of space.

-Prometheus_Hidden_Services [http://prometh5th5t5rfd.onion/]: with this you can run a virtual machine based in the dark web.

This one is free.

-Liberty’s Hackers [http://libertygb2nyeyay.onion/]

Post Scriptum: some of these links may be dead, last time I checked they worked. Of course the topic of your blog have to be something legal, otherwise these providers will shut your site.